# Function that compares two collections of strings as if they are unordered

Tags: rust, vector

I would like to implement a function to compare two collections of strings. The function should compare them as if they are unordered.

In Python, I would implement something like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator

def unordered_eq(a: Iterator[str], b: Iterator[str]):
    a = sorted(a)
    b = sorted(b)
    assert a == b
```

I tried implementing something similar in Rust. I'm trying to collect both iterators into new `Vec<&str>` instances, then `sort()` each of those vectors, then finally do a simple `assert_eq!(a, b)`.

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

fn unordered_eq<T, U, V, W>(a: T, b: V)
where
    T: Iterator<Item = U>,
    U: AsRef<str>,
    V: Iterator<Item = W>,
    W: AsRef<str>,
{
    let mut a: Vec<&str> = a.collect();
    let mut b: Vec<&str> = b.collect();
    a.sort();
    b.sort();
    assert_eq!(a, b);
}

fn main() {
    // Example usage:
    struct Item {
        path: String,
    }

    let items: Vec<Item> = vec![
        Item {path: String::from("hello")},
        Item {path: String::from("hello2")},
        Item {path: String::from("hello3")},
        Item {path: String::from("hello4")},
        Item {path: String::from("world")},
    ];

    unordered_eq(
        items.iter().map(|x| x.path.as_str()),
        ["hello", "hello2", "hello3", "hello4", "world"]
            .iter()
            .map(|x| x.deref()),
    );
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72f897d1a2b023a326b07aacb45ef094)</sup>

When I try compiling the code, I get an error:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<&str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `U`
```

Why is this the case? Since `U` implements `AsRef<str>`, I'd expect it to be able to convert to a `&str`. How do I fix this function?

Comment: `std::ops::*` isn't really meant to be imported unless you implement some of the traits, just use `*x` instead of `x.deref()` or better yet in your case `.iter().copied()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.collect()` is implemented for types that have a `FromIterator<T>` implementation, there is no such implementation for `Vec<T>` where `T: AsRef<str>`.
You can use the `AsRef` implementation yourself though:

```rust
fn unordered_eq<T, U, V, W>(a: T, b: V)
where
    T: Iterator<Item = U>,
    U: AsRef<str>,
    V: Iterator<Item = W>,
    W: AsRef<str>,
{
    let mut a: Vec<&str> = a.map(|x| x.as_ref()).collect();
    let mut b: Vec<&str> = b.map(|x| x.as_ref()).collect();
    a.sort();
    b.sort();
    assert_eq!(a, b);
}
```

but now we run into the issue that `as_ref` only takes a reference and we throw away the objects so we have to store them somewhere first:

```rust
fn unordered_eq<T, U, V, W>(a: T, b: V)
where
    T: Iterator<Item = U>,
    U: AsRef<str>,
    V: Iterator<Item = W>,
    W: AsRef<str>,
{
    let a : Vec<U> = a.collect();
    let b : Vec<W> = b.collect();
    let mut a: Vec<&str> = a.iter().map(U::as_ref).collect();
    let mut b: Vec<&str> = b.iter().map(W::as_ref).collect();
    a.sort();
    b.sort();
    assert_eq!(a, b);
}
```

So as you can see being generic in the item of the iterators makes things quite cumbersome.
Instead I'd just let the caller worry about converting the items, but be more flexible in the actual collections I take instead:

```rust
fn unordered_eq<'a, T, V>(a: T, b: V) -> bool
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>,
    V: IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>,
{
    let mut a: Vec<&str> = a.into_iter().collect();
    let mut b: Vec<&str> = b.into_iter().collect();
    a.sort();
    b.sort();
    assert_eq!(a, b);
}

fn main() {
    let items = [
        "hello".to_string(),
        "hello2".to_string(),
        "hello3".to_string(),
        "hello4".to_string(),
        "world".to_string(),
    ];
    unordered_eq(
        items.iter().map(String::as_str),
        ["hello", "hello2", "hello3", "hello4", "world"],
    );
}
```